# Unable to run Kiwi tests on iOS8 device

Tags: ios8, xcode6, cocoapods, xctest, kiwi

I am trying to run Kiwi (installed via CocoaPods) tests on iOS8 device but the build fails with the following linking errors:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestSuite", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$__KWAllTestsSuite in libPods-TestTests.a(KWAllTestsSuite.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestSuite", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$__KWAllTestsSuite in libPods-TestTests.a(KWAllTestsSuite.o)
      objc-class-ref in libPods-TestTests.a(KWAllTestsSuite.o)
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_XCTestSuite_$_KWConfiguration in libPods-TestTests.a(KWAllTestsSuite.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_TestTests in TestTests.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_KWSpec in libPods-TestTests.a(KWSpec.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_TestTests in TestTests.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_KWSpec in libPods-TestTests.a(KWSpec.o)
  "__XCTFailureHandler", referenced from:
      -[TestTests testExample] in TestTests.o
  "__XCTFailureFormat", referenced from:
      -[TestTests testExample] in TestTests.o
  "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$__XCTestCaseInterruptionException", referenced from:
  GCC_except_table2 in TestTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

Tests are building and running on every available simulator.
XCTest tests without Kiwi are being built and run succesfully on iOS 8 device as well.

**EDIT 31.10** Removed link to test project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` to your project's Build Settings => Framework Search Paths

[image]

Answer (score 1):

add `-framework XCTest` to `Other Linker Flags` in your xcode project